# F# Library structure

Tags: f#, structure, lib

I'm doing some restructuring of a project of mine, and decided to make a separate library project for a big part of it.

My problem lays in that I have multiple files with modules where many of them should be hidden from user API, how do I achieve this? I have not tried this before so are unfamiliar to how the library structure are different from commandline projects, and how to scope things correctly. If I can see every file in the lib project from
other project why do we have the Library.fs file?

To formalize a little. Say that I have SomeCode.fs and Library.fs

#### SomeCode.fs

```
module SomeCode

type SomeType = ...

let someFunc1 ... = ...

// things to hide here

// depend on hidden code
let SomeFunc2 ... = ...
```

#### Library.fs

```
namespace SomeLib

module Mod1 = ...
```

This is intended to target other F# project. How to structure this so the API would only see the right things, and still be maintainable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`internal` is your friend here. If you declare a module

```
module internal MyNamSpace.MySecretModule
```

this is only accessible from within your project.

The module `Library` you keep public, and this is your API.

`internal` can also be used on individual functions, in case you want to hide just some functions.

A fairly common way of hiding part of a module is also to employ the following pattern

```
module MyModule =

    [<AutoOpen>]
    module internal MySecretModule =
        let apa = 1
        // Bunch of other internal stuff

    // Can use stuff from MySecretModule, but other projects cannot
    let bepa = apa + 1
```

Comment: but what if i have parts code parts in the module that should not be hidden?

Comment: See expanded answer

Comment: It has been altered since I asked. But thanks that helped a lot. I'm decoupling my lexer/parser interpreter, from my compiler, and a lot of the stuff in the code should not be used outside specific parts